# Is "At which address should I come?" correct?

Tags: prepositions

The sentence is,

> **At** which address should I come?

Which preposition should be used? Can I use "on"?

Comment: What about this : "Where am I supposed to go?" ?

Answer (score 3):

Since *come* is a verb signaling motion, you should use the preposition "to:"

> To which address should I come?

Comment: Perhaps the tweak: *"To which address should I go?"* -- (For the *in situ* version would be: "I should go to which address?") -- Though, perhaps both versions ("go" and "come") could be acceptable . . .

Comment: @F.E. it's awkward, I agree. I pictured I situation where I was driving to a friend's house, but didn't know the exact address, so I called him and asked "to which address should I come?" Realistically, I don't think I'd ever ask it that way though.   Side note: "At which address should I *arrive*?" would be correct.

Comment: Actually, that context (in your comment) makes the "come" version fine, imo. Echoing situations could also work for it too--where the previous dialogue used the verb "come" in it. -- As to the "arrive" version, ah, that one sounds unusual to me.

Comment: More realistically common, though, would be either “Where should I go?” or “What’s the address?”.